# need help with configuring virtual host on apache

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I have the following in my sites-enabled:

```
#
#  Example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-available/adityaherlambang.com)
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@adityaherlambang.com
        ServerName  www.adityaherlambang.com
        ServerAlias adityaherlambang.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/adityaherlambang.com/htdocs/

        # CGI Directory
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/adityaherlambang.com/cgi-bin/
        <Location /cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Location>


        # Logfiles
        ErrorLog  /var/www/adityaherlambang.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/adityaherlambang.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In my virtual.conf I have:

```
#  We're running multiple virtual hosts.
#

NameVirtualHost *:80
```

I was just following the tutorial [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412). Why is it that now when I restart my server I am getting:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                             [Sun Aug 14 04:35:30 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Sun Aug 14 04:35:30 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting .......[Sun Aug 14 04:35:42 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Sun Aug 14 04:35:42 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

My etc hosts looks like:

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1.:80 adityaherlambang.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: That `/etc/hosts` is... well, polite words fail me.  I'll go with "wrong", at the risk of understating the problem too much.

Comment: so how do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VirtualHost` does not have a default port; when you say `<virtualHost *>` you mean *all* ports on *all* addresses. You need to use `*:80` instead.

Comment: why does the tutorial shows it like that?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't show it like you've implemented it.

Comment: before this I used NameVirtualHost * and <virtualHost *:80> and it didn't work as well

Comment: and even after changing that.. I am still getting 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                    [Sun Aug 14 05:14:51 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting [Sun Aug 14 05:14:52 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio was correct, but I just wanted to expand.

If you take a look at the docs for [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost). You can see the syntax calls for an IP and then a port. This doesn't mean Apache will listen on the port you specify here, or even if you just use `NameVirtualHost *` doesn't mean it will listen to every port. Apache has the [Listen directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) which defines which port Apache listens on.

By setting `NameVirtualHost *:80` What you are doing is saying on all request that come in on port 80, run it through name-based virtual hosting. So if you just had `NameVirtualHost *` your telling apache that not matter where the request come from, run it through name-based virtual hosting. If specified an IP, then only that IP would be subject to virutalhost.

So the easy answer would be always have your NameVirtualHost match your virtual host. But I think understanding why is important. Because one day you might have that crazy server where it has `Listen 80 8080 81` and NameVirtualHost is only set up on 8080 and 81?? Could happen.